# How to make AngularJS throw error instead of silently failing when template cannot be retrieved?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, razor, angular-routing

I use razor views for `ng-view` templates. `templateUrl` contains path to `'cshtml'` instead of static `'html'`.

Sometimes razor file is invalid due to mistypings and mvc returns state 500 when view compilation fails.

Unfortunately, angular says nothing in this case. I'd like to see an exception in console.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: You can listen for $routeChangeError on $rootScope to find out about the problem, then use $log to write out information from the parameters associated with the event (currentRoute, previousRoute, rejection), it's the rejection you'll want to inspect closely.